# Create a table wih php and mysql having fields php variables

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a mysql table and all its fields being php variables. Why I  got errors executing this code?

```
$stmttt = $pdo->query("
    CREATE TABLE $test (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    $name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    $tel VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    $email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    $city VARCHAR(50),
    CMSdate TIMESTAMP)
    ");
```

Comment: What data was in the PHP variables? And what errors did you get? .. i advice you to place the SQL string in a PHP variable `$sql = "
    CREATE TABLE $test (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    $name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    $tel VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    $email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    $city VARCHAR(50),
    CMSdate TIMESTAMP)
    "`  and `echo` or `var_dump()` the `$sql`variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{}` to escape your variables properly. Try with

```
$stmttt = $pdo->query("
    CREATE TABLE ${test} (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ${name} VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    ${tel} VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ${email} VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ${city} VARCHAR(50),
    CMSdate TIMESTAMP)
");
```

Also have a look a working example [here](http://codepad.org/9dy0peOF)